# jquery recalculate width/height after ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a navigation bar which follows me on page scroll. The problem I am facing it that if I perform an ajax-call which loads extra content to the page and page height increases, the navigation bar-rules needs to be recalculated (maximal y e.g. where it needs to stop to it don't overlay the footer)

cna I solve this with onajaxcomplete or is there a general method where I can recalculate rules (which I applied initially) everytime the page size changes?

Comment: you can do it in the ajax callback like .always() or use a global [ajaxComplete()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/)

Comment: the page needs to be rendered before I can recalculate the correct values. does ajaxComplete is called AFTER oder BEFORE the page is completely re-rendered?